Proper site to ask how to construct an Archimedes' screw
I want to ask on how earlier cultures would be able to construct an Archimedes' screw.
I am pretty sure this is not the proper site for that question, so I ask on meta to direct me where to ask.
The background is that I wonder if our forefathers could have constructed better water wheels. The structure is quite obvious, considering wounded seashells and remains of shark stomachs. To see how to use it is more demanding, and how to build it on a scale large enough to lift water, given the materials available time ago has not been mastered by any culture.

I wonder if [history.se] might accept the topic about "how did they build", but not sure about the hypothetical "could have constructed better"
